# Transforming vector field on a manifold into canonical field

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, vector-fields, parametrization, pushforward

Let $M$ be a $C^{k}$ differentiable manifold of dimension $n$, and let $X$ be a $C^{k}$ vector field on $M$. Let $p$ be a point of $M$ such that $X(p) \neq 0$: is there a local parametrization $(\varphi, U)$ (where $U$ is a neighbourhood of $M$ containing $p$ and $\varphi : U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$) such that the push forward of $X$ with respect to $\phi$ is a canonical field (that is, $\varphi_{*}X(u)=e_{i}(u)$ for every $u \in U$, where $e_{i}$ is the constant vector field parallel to the $i$-th versor) ?

Comment: This is often called the Flowbox Theorem. See this [Wiki entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straightening_theorem_for_vector_fields) for a brief discussion.